# Fazer uma query em Linq e ver no index

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Queria uma query em linq que mostra os atributos da tabela disponibilidade e o nome do respectivo catequista que se encontra na tabela pessoa.
No index irá aparecer:

```
 Nome | AnoPastoral | DiaDisponivel | HoraDisponivel | Observacoes
```

Estou a ter dificuldades na query e não sei como mostrar no index.

Models:

```
public partial class Pessoa {    
    [Key]       
    public int PessoaID { get; set; }
    public String Nome { get; set; }
    public String Morada { get; set; }
    public String Localidade { get; set; }
    public String CodPostal { get; set; }
    public String Telemovel { get; set; }
    public virtual Catequista Catequista { get; set; }
}

public partial class Catequista {

    //chave primária e chave forasteira
    [Key, ForeignKey("Pessoa")]
    public int CatequistaID { get; set; }
    public String Formacao_Eclisiastica { get; set; }  
    public String Catecismo_Pretendido { get; set; }
    public String Data_Inicio_Atividade { get; set; }
    public String ParoquiaInicioAtividade { get; set; }

    // referencia os dados da 'pessoa' associada ao catequista
    public virtual Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }
}    
public partial class Disponibilidade {

        //chave primária
        public int DisponibilidadeID { get; set; }
        public String AnoPastoral { get; set; }
        public String DiaDisponivel { get; set; }
        public String HoraDisponivel { get; set; }
        public String Observacoes { get; set; }
        //chave estrangeira
        public int CatequistaID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CatequistaID")]

        public virtual Catequista Catequista { get; set; }
    }
```

Controlador:

```
   public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var disponibilidade = (from d in db.Disponibilidade
                                   join c in db.Catequista on d.CatequistaID equals c.CatequistaID
                                   join p in db.Pessoa on c.CatequistaID equals p.PessoaID
                                   where c.CatequistaID == d.CatequistaID
                                   select new { Nome = p.Nome, AnoPastoral = d.AnoPastoral, DiaDisponivel = d.DiaDisponivel, HoraDisponivel = d.HoraDisponivel, Observacoes = d.Observacoes });                                
            return View(disponibilidade.ToList());
        }
```

Comment: Não entendi a dificuldade da exibição. A query executa corretamente?

Comment: Sim já testei a query com um breakpoint e está a retornar o que pretendo mas não sei como exibir no index da minha View.

Comment: `@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>

        <th>
            @Html.DisplayFor(????)
        </th>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que a sentença está certa. Apenas considero que precisamos tipar o objeto de retorno:

```
public class DisponibilidadeViewModel
{
    // Não sei os tipos das suas variáveis, então vou colocar tudo String.
    // Fique à vontade pra definir os tipos corretos.
    public String Nome { get; set; }
    public String AnoPastoral { get; set; }
    public String DiaDisponivel { get; set; }
    public String HoraDisponivel { get; set; }
    public String Observacoes { get; set; }
}
```

O *Controller* ficaria assim:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var disponibilidade = (from d in db.Disponibilidade
                               join c in db.Catequista on d.CatequistaID equals c.CatequistaID
                               join p in db.Pessoa on c.CatequistaID equals p.PessoaID
                               where c.CatequistaID == d.CatequistaID
                               select new DisponibilidadeViewModel { Nome = p.Nome, AnoPastoral = d.AnoPastoral, DiaDisponivel = d.DiaDisponivel, HoraDisponivel = d.HoraDisponivel, Observacoes = d.Observacoes });                                
        return View(disponibilidade.ToList());
    }
```

A *View* ficaria assim:

```
@model IEnumerable<MeuProjeto.ViewModels.DisponibilidadeViewModel>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Ano Pastoral</th>
            <th>Dia Disponível</th>
            <th>Hora Disponível</th>
            <th>Observações</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model) 
        { 
            <tr> 
                <td>@item.Nome</td>
                <td>@item.AnoPastoral</td>
                <td>@item.DiaDisponivel</td>
                <td>@item.HoraDisponivel</td>
                <td>@item.Observacoes</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Está a dar erro no compilador e não consigo resolver. 
Mensagem de erro do compilador: "CS1963: Uma árvore de expressões poderá não conter uma operação dinâmica". o erro é nos "item"..

Comment: É por causa do `DisplayFor`. Veja agora.

Comment: Continua com problemas."'object' não contém uma definição para 'Nome'".

Comment: Seria problema você tipar este retorno? Criando um *ViewModel*, por exemplo?

Comment: Não seria problema. Mas não sei como isso seria feito.

Comment: @user10271 Veja agora.

Comment: Obrigado. Problema Resolvido